# "forever list" says "No forever process running" but it is running an app

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, module

I have started an app with

```
forever start app.js
```

After that I typed,

```
forever list
```

and it shows that

```
The "sys" module is now called "util". It should have a similar interface.
info:   No forever processes running
```

But I checked my processes with

```
ps aux | grep node
```

and it shows that

```
root      1184  0.1  1.5 642916  9672 ?        Ss   05:37   0:00 node     
/usr/local/bin/forever start app.js
root      1185  0.1  2.1 641408 13200 ?        Sl   05:37   0:00 node 
/var/www/app.js
ubuntu    1217  0.0  0.1   7928  1060 pts/0    S+   05:41   0:00 grep --color=auto node
```

I cannot control over the process, since I cannot list the process in "forever list"

How can I let "Forever" knowing its running processes and let having control over its running processes.

Comment: Are you running `forever list` as root as well?

Comment: @emostar I ran "forever list" at /var/www

Comment: You should have some info in `~/.forever` or in your case `/root/.forever`. So it doesn't matter what directory you are in, but what user you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same problem today.

in my case: i'm using NVM and forgot that it doesn't set/modify the global node path, so i had to set it manually

```
export NODE_PATH="/root/.nvm/v0.6.0/bin/node"
```

Answer (score 13):

`forever list` should be invoked with same user as that of processes.
Generally it is root user (in case of ubuntu upstart unless specified) so you can switch to root user using `sudo su` and then try `forever list`.

PS. Moved to [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) recently which has lot more features than forever.

Answer (score 1):

If you exec the `forever start app.js` within init.d you should later type `sudo HOME=/home/pi/devel/web-app -u root forever list` to have the correct list.

Answer (score 1):

A fix would be great for this.
Encountered this one as well.

I believe an this issue was logged [here](https://github.com/foreversd/forever/issues/483).

What I could recommend for now is to find the process that's using your node port e.g. 3000. Like so:

```
sudo lsof -t -i:3000
```

That command will show the process id.

Then kill the process by performing:

```
kill PID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo su
forever list
```

This will output the correct list (processes started by root user).

Comment: `HOME=/root` shouldn't be necessary, `sudo` already runs the command as the root user.

Comment: Both gave different results in my case.